# Will a console process ran without a window exit with with my program?

Tags: c#, shell, process, console

will a process started with these settings:

```
                p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
                p.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
                p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
```

close when my program closes? or crashes? for that matter?

Comment: Just kill it and find out. I very much suspect it will live on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No... it only terminates either by exiting itself or being killed either by your process or some other process or by the user (for example via Task Manager) - see for reference http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.aspx